# Not retrieving schema list from source when migrating from MSSQL to MySQL using Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, migrate

I'm trying to migrate my database which is in MS SQL Server to MySQL, I'm using Workbench to do so.
I get connection to both databases but get the following warning:

```
Retrieve schema list from source.
```

And this is the message log:

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connect to source DBMS done
Check target DBMS connection...
- Connecting to target...
Connecting to Mysql@74.5.3.2:3306...
Connecting to Mysql@74.5.3.2:3306...
Connected
Check target DBMS connection done
Retrieve schema list from source....
- Checking connection...
- Fetching catalog names...
WARNING: The following catalogs where not found: Autotask
- Fetching schema names...
- Finished
Retrieve schema list from source finished
Tasks finished with warnings and/or errors, view the logs for details
Finished performing tasks.
```

Autotask is the name of the db.
Please what am I doing wrong?

Note: even with the warning the wizard let me click next, but the next screen is supposed to list schematas, but as it is empty I can't continue.

Thanks in advance.
Pablo

Comment: I am also having this issue, using SQL Server Native Client 10.0 to connect to a sql server 2008. The connection succeeds but the Schemata Selection is an empty list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're connecting to MS SQL as user "sa". Non-admin users may lack rights that are necessary to extract schemas...

Comment: Please no. This is sufficient, but runs against "principle of least privilege".

Answer (score 44):

In case someone else comes across this same issue, and you don't have access to the "sa" user, I thought I'd post how to resolve the issue.

The underlying problem is user permissions. Although you can login to the database fine there is a specific permission that needs to be set in order for it to work with MySQL Workbench. The permission you need is "View Any Definition" which is found under the users "Securables" tab.

There is a good short video explaining it all here http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/08/video-tutorial-setup-a-restricted-sql-server-account-for-migrations-with-mysql-workbench/ and the specific part is located at 2:17.

If the database is on a shared host - as was the one I needed to access - I would recommend simply emailing the host (preferably via your clients main contact) and they will hopefully do it for you. The host in my case switched it on for 1 day as there must be some other potential security risks at their end having it turned on.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

[image: Management Studio > Server > Security > Logins > User > Properties > Securables > Explicit > View any definition > Grant]

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer to this.  Thank you.  This solved so many problems so quickly.