# MySql workbanch migration wizard does not retrieve schema

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to migrate from azure SQL to Google Cloud MySql using MySql Workbench  migration wizard.

I am using the administrative user to connect to azure SQL.
The 'Fetch Schema List' finishes successfully with the message "Retrieve schema list from source finished" but no schema are available in the "Schema Selection" stage.

What am I doing wrong?

p.s.
The solution mentioned in [Not retrieving schema list from source when migrating from MSSQL to MySQL using Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038716/not-retrieving-schema-list-from-source-when-migrating-from-mssql-to-mysql-using) by @SaRiD does not solve the problem.